# Dark souls PC controls - Help with aiming and switching between weapons

Tags: pc, dark-souls

After watching a youtube video I realised three things:

1. That console players can aim, and lock on targets. Can PC players,
   and if so, how?
2. That you can switch between weapon sets with the
   press of a single button. As with 1 - how can I do that on PC.
3. That my idiocy/ignorance may have been making things unnecessarily hard on myself. Is there help available for that?

Currently I pretty much walk around cowering with shield up at all times. I wait for something to attack so that I can take a quick swing in return, and all the time praying nothing gets behind me.

Comment: Use a controller. I've not played the PC version, but by all accounts the keyboard/mouse controls are garbage. Dark Souls is meant to be played with a controller.

Comment: Also, *"Currently I pretty much walk around cowering with shield up at all times. I wait for something to attack so that I can take a quick swing in return, and all the time praying nothing gets behind me."* - this is how most people play Dark Souls, regardless of platform or controls.

Comment: Thanks for the info and know that I am not playing it too far wrong :), but I probably wont be getting a controller. I Would still like to know  if there are answers to points 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to force you to buy a controller :-). But just know that the keyboard controls are basically only there because they have to be, not because the developer thinks they are in any way adequate for playing the game. I'm sure there are answers for your points 1 and 2 though... I just don't know what they are.

Comment: There is a community mod called 'DSMfix' which alleviates a lot of the native mouse and keyboard issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to answer these to the best of my abilities...

1. Press O to lockon target/ Reset Camera (as in making the camera facing in the direction your character is facing. If you need extra help moving the mouse to aim, consider downloading this mod to help. It should smooth out the mouse and make camera control easier. [**Mouse Fix**](http://darksouls.nexusmods.com/mods/28/)
2. Press V to switch the right weapon and C to switch the left weapon/shield/catalyst. Also, press F to switch items and R to switch your magic you have attuned.
3. As for this, just keep in mind that for PVE, you should be fine as long as you can accept that the game is going to be hell of a lot harder for you. PVP, good luck. PVP is going to be a mess for you, mainly because controllers in this game have a LARGE advantage over Mouse/Keyboard players. If you plan to main PVP consider investing into a controller that you can use.

The PC controls in my opinion are an absolute failure. Now, I am not bashing the game being bad, just that the developers did not intend players to use PC controls. Although, I am sure that if you are skilled enough, you can beat the game.

Now last note, what you currently do is good practice, but for bosses try to predict their patterns and dodge them. Dodging, if done right, should be more effective than pure blocking because it should leave more stamina and let you have more control of the fight unlike blocking and then being limited to only more blocking or rolling away to heal. 
Unless you use a pure strength build and withstand the damage dodging should be a better choice.

Comment: Just thought of something in case you need some clarification. PVP means Player Vs. Player. PVE means Player Vs. Environment (as in you verses the game). Some people don't make the connection or are bad with abbreviations so just in case I provided them for you.

Comment: Ha, very comprehensive, thank you. Yes, as far as PvP goes anytime anyone invades my world I am pretty much resigned to death - but it feels like beyond out controlling me they are also higher level, and or have fancier items and spells... Oh god the spells.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about the controls on keyboard/mouse. The game has too many buttons to be like other PC games on the keyboard/mouse. I own all three consoles and still love PC games. I can aim and move better. But that's just me. I swapped the controls
I use tab to target lock, Q to use whatever is loaded on the bottom, flasks etc. E for interact. I use the arrows to swap the items, weapons etc. Like this it feels like many other games I have played but isn't identical. I use space to dash and shift to jump. WASD to move. The left and right mouse felt wrong since all other games are swing/shoot left and block/aim right so I swapped those. I also moved the dash, block walk to the three keys along the space bar. So it's all within reach. I'm over 200 already killed a bunch of bosses and PVP is just fine. About 50/50 now. But I put that into the fact that I am running a generally PVE build and when I get summoned or invaded I don't get to say time out let me switch up. LOL
Don't lose hope. I almost gave up a zillion times. It does get easier. I said I own all three consoles but have a horrible time with the controllers due to an injury I had years ago that left my right arm and hand partially paralyzed and I have no feeling in the fingers. It makes tactile controls really jerky and hard. So I am stuck. Hate to be told to buy a controller though I see the reason. I can't even if I wanted to. I hate scrolling through items instead of selecting 1,2,3,... Etc but you basically adapt prepare and learn.